# How to load navigation properties using POCO Entities in EF by having managed lifespan ObjectContext?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, poco, objectcontext

I am following the same article as follows [Managing Entity Framework ObjectContext lifespan](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/Managing-Entity-Framework-ObjectContext-lifespan-and-scope-in-n-layered-ASP-NET-applications.aspx).

I generate the Entities from my EDMX file by using "POCO Entity Generator" tool and put all the Entities in class library. I have my model (EDMX) in separate class library.

I referenced Test.Entities.dll and Test.Model.dll in my data access layer class library.
In my class library I have UnitOfWorkScope and FacadeBase classes that they take care of my ObjectContext. and all the other classes are inherited from FacadeBase class.

```
Public Class WorkOrderDAL
    Inherits FacadeBase(Of Test.Entities.WorkOrder)
```

Here is the FacadeBase

```
Public MustInherit Class FacadeBase(Of T As System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject)
    Private _objectContextManager As ObjectContextManager(Of Test.Model.MyDataContext)
```

Here is one of the Entity classes in Test.Entities.dll.

```
Partial Public Class WorkOrder
    Inherits Global.System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject
```

I have the compiled query in my DataAceessLayer,
but **It didn't return the navigation properties related to the object**. Here is the sample of that.

```
    ReadOnly qWorkOrderIDByWorkOrderID As Func(Of LAITEntities, Integer, IQueryable(Of WorkOrder)) = _
CompiledQuery.Compile(Of LAITEntities, Integer, IQueryable(Of WorkOrder))( _
          Function(LAIT As LAITEntities, WorkOrderID As Integer) _
              LAIT.WorkOrder.Include("Customer") _
                            .Include("Computer") _
                            .Include("Computer.Condition") _
                            .Include("Computer.Device") _
                            .Include("Computer.Brand") _
                            .Include("Computer.OS") _
                            .Where(Function(w) w.WorkOrderID = WorkOrderID))

Public Function SelectByWorkOrderID(ByVal WorkOrderID As Integer) As WorkOrder
    Dim _result = qWorkOrderIDByWorkOrderID.Invoke(ObjectContext, WorkOrderID).AsEnumerable.SingleOrDefault
    Return _result
End Function
```